# How to create clickable row in liferay-ui search container

Tags: java, liferay

I want to show detail after click on searched row in liferay-ui search container.

My code:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${data}" total="${count}" />  

<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="test.Foo" modelVar="foo" >

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="..." property="..." orderable="true" orderableProperty="..." />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="..." property="..." orderable="true" orderableProperty="..." />                          

</liferay-ui:search-container-row>

<liferay-ui:search-iterator/>
```

How to create row clickable? i dont want make clickable column. and i cannot use javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use the attribute **href**

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="..." property="..." href="...possibly use a renderUrl...." />
```

Comment: a want to make clickable row, not column

Comment: The code i gave you is what you want, use the attribute in every search-container-column-text